# Embed Google Doc list to web page

Tags: php, html, embed, google-docs

I tried searching the web but couldn't find the answer.  Is there any way I can add some code to my web page to display the content/list of documents from my Google doc folder, and make them available for download?  I know that currently we can share a specific link to a file, or add a link to the folder, but I need to how the list directly on my page.  Eg: Google maps, or Google calendar.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is usefull to you:

http://wp-wizzard.com/external-data/get-a-list-of-public-spreadsheets-from-google-docs

Similar question:
[php zend gdata - Get list of google docs using oauth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10253490/php-zend-gdata-get-list-of-google-docs-using-oauth)